# custom left sidebar react native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, sidebar

am looking to do something custom drawer like this [image: photo]
when click ' go to home ' or ' go to contact ' etc.. ,  it will open the page appropriate pagein the right side and keeping the left menu open always..
i found this package createDrawerNavigator  from react-navigation , but i cant customize..

here my code

```
<NavigationContainer >
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   <Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    drawerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#c6cbef',
      width: 240,
    },
  }}
>
  {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawerstyle

Comment: THANks for ur reply , but the problem isnt with drawerStyle.. am looking for anathor solution ..and without auto hide left menu , and without hamburger icon